# I can't use a custom function in Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, custom-function

I just started with Apps Script and I'm facing an issue. I am trying to use a custom function in a google sheet but I get the error "NAME?". My guess is that Google Apps Script does not have permission to access my Sheet files. 
Coud anyone help me? 
Thank you

Comment: From your script editor go to the help menu and go to API reference and search for custom functions and read about all of the restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. turns out the binding wasn't done. I was trying to use a function defined in a stadalone script.